# How can I use "map" inside a "for" loop in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I'm trying to use `map` inside a `for` loop, but this code is not working. This code should print `1` and `2` three times. But the code below produces no output. It will only partially work if you uncomment the `exit` line. Any idea why? I tested it using the current Perl 6 version (Rakudo version 2015.12-79-g4bb47d5 built on MoarVM version 2015.12 and also the Windows version).

```
for (1..3) {
 map { say $_ }, (1..2);
# exit;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a look at

```
say (map { say $_ }, 1..2).WHAT;
```

This tells us `&map` returns a `Seq`, which is a lazy construct.

Additionally, the last statement in the body of a `for` loop is used to aggregate its return value, cf

```
my @list = do for 1..3 {
    map { say $_ }, 1..2;
}

say .WHAT for @list;
```

If you add another statement after the call to `&map`, the call will be in 'sink context' and gets evaluated eagerly.

This can also be forced explicitly:

```
for 1..3 {
    sink map { say $_ }, 1..2;
}
```

Alternatively, just use another `for` loop:

```
for 1..3 {
    .say for 1..2;
}
```

Comment: You can also force it to be an eager sequence by using `eager` instead of `sink`. Really `for` should just put all of its statements into `sink` context if it isn't preceded by a `do` ( `do for 1..3 { … }` )

Comment: Seems the lesson here is: be careful about using a filter function like map for side effects as if it's a loop.